# freeipa migrate from v3 to v4

Tags: ipa, freeipa

My goal is to migrate from freeipa v3 to v4. Both versions are a cluster of two nodes.

v3 is centos 6 and v4 is centos 7.

I want to migrate the dns entries from the old cluster to the new one. Both have the same dns zone(s) and after all dns entries are on both clusters I will migrate all hosts to the new cluster.
Also the users will be created manually. Goal is to have a fresh freeipa environment.

Which commands do I need to know or use to achieve that?
Also an export and import function will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This is all documented in the official documentation in the "MIGRATING IDENTITY MANAGEMENT FROM RED HAT ENTERPRISE LINUX 6 TO VERSION 7" section:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/linux_domain_identity_authentication_and_policy_guide/migrate-6-to-7

The key is not to start from scratch but rather add CentOS 7 replicas to CentOS 6 deployment, move services over to CentOS 7 replicas and then decommission CentOS 6 machines. This is, in general, much easier and more reliable to do than to start from scratch by importing older data.